# How to get map to properly use resized container?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've searched quite a bit and can't figure this out. I'm updating a map from v2 to v3. It allows the user to resize the map container. After changing the container size, in v2 I just did `map.checkResize()` and it just worked. For the v3 version, I used `map.fitBounds(map.getBounds())` and it doesn't do anything I can see. I maintain a crosshair marker right at the center of the container, so it's obvious the v3 resize is not working right.

I've also tried placing the bounds functions in a 'bounds_changed' event callback function, as well as `map.setOptions(mapOptions)` both in and outside of the callback. It's clear the map is unaware of the container size change. How do I get the map to recognize the new container size?

This is currently on a local test server so I can't provide a link. I could make an illustrative  sample on a live server, but I'm hoping this a generic enough question to make that unnecessary. I don't need specific code, I just want to know what basic steps I need to do to get the map to work properly in it's new container size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v2 `map.checkResize()`, the code in v3 uses like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

And getting the size of map container like this:

```
var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
var size = new google.maps.Size(mapDiv.offsetWidth, mapDiv.offsetHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks! I would have never figured this out on my own. Documentation is somewhere between obscure and non-existent.